# Rails: simple asset pipeline issue with images breaking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have an Item and each item has a string image column where I store the path to an image in assets like `assets/images/items/1.jpg`

If I call `some_item.image`, then I'll receive the path to that image like `"/assets/items/1.jpg"`

If I go into a view and write `<img src="/assets/items/1.jpg">` then I will see the proper image. But with image_tag `<%= image_tag(some_item.image) %>`, the image tag is populated like `<img src="images/assets/items/1.jpg">` which does not properly show the image.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `image_tag`, you should use the [`image_path()` or `image_url()` helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) instead.

consider the following:

```
img = 'some_image.png'
image_tag(img)  #=> <img src="some_image.png"/>
image_path(img) #=> <img src="/assets/some_image.png"/>
image_url(img)  #=> <img src="http://host.ext/assets/some_image.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to define a method on your Item model which return a valid path for `image_tag`:

Example:

```
def image_path
  self.image_path.sub(/^\/assets\//, '') 
  # removes '/assets/' from the start of the string
  # returns a String like 'items/1.png'
end
```

in your view:

```
= image_tag(item.image_path)
```